# Rotate an object around another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, trigonometry

I'm having problem with a project of mine, I want to rotate an planet on it's orbit around the sun to a certain degree that comes from an equation. I'm looking for a way to rotate a planet withount a need of doing 360 classes in CSS just to change them everytime. That degree is calculated from latitude and the angle of the planet's inclination, here's my code so far

```
function gorowanie(){
    var wysokosc=document.getElementById("licz1").value;
    var nachylenie=document.getElementById("licz2").value;
    var polkola=document.getElementById("lista").value;
    var wynik=0;
    if(polkola=="1"){wynik=90-Number(wysokosc)+Number(nachylenie);}
    else if(polkola=="2"){wynik=90+Number(wysokosc)+Number(nachylenie);}
    else{wynik=90;}
    document.getElementById("linia").style.transform="rotate("+(Number(wynik)-90)+"deg)";
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=wynik+"°";
}
```

If it helps I'll throw a photo of the project here
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/puLKU.png)

I was looking for something that can help me with that but sadly I just can't find anything that could help me, I was trying to use translate somehow but I just can't seem to get a good outcome.
I would be thankfull if someone gave me an idea how to do it.

Comment: Note that this isn't really a JS problem, just a general math problem related to CSS transforms. Also note that SO is an English only board, so rewriting your code to use variables that folks who can read English can understand is important (because variable names tell us what they're going to be used for, which means we can spot when you're not being used correctly). And of course, remember to format your code, you're asking humans to read it, not asking a computer to run it =)

Comment: here is a tip how to rotate an element from a center https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PogOZVy hope that gives you some easy hint ;)

Comment: You could make each planet's parent element able to encapsulate the whole orbit, push the planet to one side of the parent, and just rotate it, because it's already centered around the sun.